# numpy method to join two meshgrids and their result arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Consider two n-dimensional, possibly overlapping, `numpy meshgrids`, say

```
m1 = (x1, y1, z1, ...)
m2 = (x2, y2, z2, ...)
```

Within `m1` and `m2` there are no duplicate coordinate tuples. Each `meshgrid` has a result array, which may result from different functions:

```
r1 = f1(m1)
r2 = f2(m2)
```

such that `f1(m) != f2(m)`. Now I would like to join those two `meshgrids` and their result arrays, e.g. `m=m1&m2` and `r=r1&r2` (where `&` would denote some kind of union), such that the coordinate tuples in `m` are still sorted and the values in `r` still correspond to the original coordinate tuples. Newly created coordinate tuples should be identifiable (for instance with a special value).

To elaborate on what I'm after, I have two examples that kind of do what I want with simple `for` and `if` statements. Here's a 1D example:

```
x1 = [1, 5, 7]
r1 = [i**2 for i in x1]

x2 = [2, 4, 6]
r2 = [i*3 for i in x2]

x,r = list(zip(*sorted([(i,j) for i,j in zip(x1+x2,r1+r2)],key=lambda x: x[0])))
```

which gives

```
x = (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7)
r = (1, 6, 12, 25, 18, 49)
```

For 2D it starts getting quite complicated:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = [1, 5, 7]
b1 = [2, 5, 6]

x1,y1 = np.meshgrid(a1,b1)
r1 = x1*y1

a2 = [2, 4, 6]
b2 = [1, 3, 8]

x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(a2,b2)
r2 = 2*x2

a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]

x,y = np.meshgrid(a,b)

r = np.ones(x.shape)*-1

for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        if   x[i,j] in a1 and y[i,j] in b1:
            r[i,j] = r1[a1.index(x[i,j]),b1.index(y[i,j])]

        elif x[i,j] in a2 and y[i,j] in b2:
            r[i,j] = r2[a2.index(x[i,j]),b2.index(y[i,j])]
```

This gives the desired result, with new coordinate pairs having the value `-1`:

```
x=
[[1 2 4 5 6 7]
 [1 2 4 5 6 7]
 [1 2 4 5 6 7]
 [1 2 4 5 6 7]
 [1 2 4 5 6 7]
 [1 2 4 5 6 7]]
y=
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3]
 [5 5 5 5 5 5]
 [6 6 6 6 6 6]
 [8 8 8 8 8 8]]
r=
[[ -1.   4.   4.  -1.   4.  -1.]
 [  2.  -1.  -1.   5.  -1.   6.]
 [ -1.   8.   8.  -1.   8.  -1.]
 [ 10.  -1.  -1.  25.  -1.  30.]
 [ 14.  -1.  -1.  35.  -1.  42.]
 [ -1.  12.  12.  -1.  12.  -1.]]
```

but this will also become slow quickly with increasing dimensions and array sizes. So here finally the question: How can this be done using only `numpy` functions. If it is not possible, what would be the fastest way to implement this in `python`. If it is anyhow relevant, I prefer using Python 3. Note that the functions I use in the examples are not the actual functions I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of some masking to replace the `A in B` parts to give us `1D` masks. Then, we can use those masks with [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to extend to desired number of dimensions.

Thus, for a `2D` case, it would be something along these lines -

```
# Initialize o/p array
r_out = np.full([len(a), len(b)],-1)           

# Assign for the IF part
mask_a1 = np.in1d(a,a1)
mask_b1 = np.in1d(b,b1)
r_out[np.ix_(mask_b1, mask_a1)] = r1.T

# Assign for the ELIF part
mask_a2 = np.in1d(a,a2)
mask_b2 = np.in1d(b,b2)
r_out[np.ix_(mask_b2, mask_a2)] = r2.T
```

`a` could be created, like so -

```
a = np.concatenate((a1,a2))
a.sort()
```

Similarly, for `b`.

Also, we could make use of indices instead of masks for use with `np.ix_`. For the same, we could use `np.searchsorted`. Thus, instead of the mask `np.in1d(a,a1)`, we could get corresponding indices with `np.searchsorted(a,a1)` and so on for the rest of the masks. This should be considerably faster.

---

For a `3D` case, I would assume that we would have another array, say `c`. Thus, the initialization part would involve using `len(c)`. There would be one more mask/index-array corresponding to `c` and hence one more term into [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and there would be transpose of `r1` and `r2`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I'm not quite sure if I understand all the details. Why do `r1` and `r2` have to be transposed? Also, to add to your answer, `a` and `b` can be constructed using `np.concatenate` and `np.sort`, i.e. `a=np.concatenate((a1,a2))` and `a.sort()` -- may be you could still add that to your answer...

Comment: @ThomasKühn It seems we need that transpose to account for the way the mesh is created with `x,y = np.meshgrid(a,b)`. Added your comments code.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer, but I still wanted to try out your second suggestion and do some profiling on the two options. Plese see my auxiliary answer below, if you're interested.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Good to see the searchsorted implementations and the confirmation that it's faster!

Answer (score 1):

Divakar's answer is exactly what I needed. I wanted, however, to still try out the second suggestion in that answer and on top I did some profiling. I thought the results may be interesting to others. Here is the code I used for profiling:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import random

def for_join_2d(x1,y1,r1, x2,y2,r2):
    """
    The algorithm from the question.
    """

    a = sorted(list(x1[0,:])+list(x2[0,:]))
    b = sorted(list(y1[:,0])+list(y2[:,0]))

    x,y = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    r = np.ones(x.shape)*-1

    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            if   x[i,j] in a1 and y[i,j] in b1:
                r[i,j] = r1[a1.index(x[i,j]),b1.index(y[i,j])]

            elif x[i,j] in a2 and y[i,j] in b2:
                r[i,j] = r2[a2.index(x[i,j]),b2.index(y[i,j])]
    return x,y,r


def mask_join_2d(x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2):
    """
    Divakar's original answer.
    """
    a = np.sort(np.concatenate((x1[0,:],x2[0,:])))
    b = np.sort(np.concatenate((y1[:,0],y2[:,0])))

    # Initialize o/p array
    x,y = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    r_out = np.full([len(a), len(b)],-1)           

    # Assign for the IF part
    mask_a1 = np.in1d(a,a1)
    mask_b1 = np.in1d(b,b1)
    r_out[np.ix_(mask_b1, mask_a1)] = r1.T

    # Assign for the ELIF part
    mask_a2 = np.in1d(a,a2)
    mask_b2 = np.in1d(b,b2)
    r_out[np.ix_(mask_b2, mask_a2)] = r2.T

    return x,y,r_out


def searchsort_join_2d(x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2):
    """
    Divakar's second suggested solution using searchsort.
    """

    a = np.sort(np.concatenate((x1[0,:],x2[0,:])))
    b = np.sort(np.concatenate((y1[:,0],y2[:,0])))

    # Initialize o/p array
    x,y = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    r_out = np.full([len(a), len(b)],-1)           

    #the IF part
    ind_a1 = np.searchsorted(a,a1)
    ind_b1 = np.searchsorted(b,b1)
    r_out[np.ix_(ind_b1,ind_a1)] = r1.T

    #the ELIF part
    ind_a2 = np.searchsorted(a,a2)
    ind_b2 = np.searchsorted(b,b2)
    r_out[np.ix_(ind_b2,ind_a2)] = r2.T

    return x,y,r_out

##the profiling code:
if __name__ == '__main__':

    N1 = 100
    N2 = 100

    coords_a = [i for i in range(N1)]
    coords_b = [i*2 for i in range(N2)]

    a1 = random.sample(coords_a, N1//2)
    b1 = random.sample(coords_b, N2//2)

    a2 = [i for i in coords_a if i not in a1]
    b2 = [i for i in coords_b if i not in b1]

    x1,y1 = np.meshgrid(a1,b1)
    r1 = x1*y1
    x2,y2 = np.meshgrid(a2,b2)
    r2 = 2*x2

    print("original for loop")
    print(min(timeit.Timer(
        'for_join_2d(x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2)',
        setup = 'from __main__ import for_join_2d,x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2',
    ).repeat(7,1000)))

    print("with masks")
    print(min(timeit.Timer(
        'mask_join_2d(x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2)',
        setup = 'from __main__ import mask_join_2d,x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2',
    ).repeat(7,1000)))

    print("with searchsort")
    print(min(timeit.Timer(
        'searchsort_join_2d(x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2)',
        setup = 'from __main__ import searchsort_join_2d,x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2',
    ).repeat(7,1000)))
```

For each function I used 7 sets of 1000 iterations and picked the fastest set for evaluation. The results for two 10x10 arrays was:

```
original for loop
0.5114614190533757

with masks
0.21544912096578628

with searchsort
0.12026709201745689
```

and for two 100x100 arrays it was:

```
original for loop
247.88183582702186

with masks
0.5245905339252204

with searchsort
0.2439237720100209
```

For big matrices the use of `numpy` functionality unsurprisingly makes a huge difference and indeed `searchsort` and indexing instead of masking about halves the run time.